# How to show Images on Gallery App on Xiaomi MIUI 8.1?

Tags: java, android, miui

This is a problem I found exclusively on Xiaomi Redmi Note 4 device (MIUI Global 8.1, Marshmallow)

So I'm making an app that generates a bitmap and saves it to FOOD folder. I have successfully generated the image and saved it to FOOD folder.

However, some of the images don't show on Gallery App. Specifically Xiaomi's Gallery App and Google's Photos. Note that some images DO show on Gallery App.

My question are:

- How to show the images in Gallery after saving the image?
- What exactly is causing this problem?

This really confuses me since it works on other devices with different OS.

This is what I have tried so far:

- I've tried using the `Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE` and `MediaScannerConnection.scanFile`.

  ```
  try {
      String fileName = imagePath.substring(imagePath.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
      MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(H5Environment.getContext().getContentResolver(), imagePath,
          fileName, null);
  } catch (Exception e) {
      DanaLog.e(TAG, e);
  }

  Intent mediaScanIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
  Uri contentUri = Uri.fromFile(new File(imagePath));
  mediaScanIntent.setData(contentUri);
  sendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);

  MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(this, 
                                  new String[]{imagePath},
                                  new String[]{"image/png"},
      new MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener() {
          @Override
          public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {
              Log.d(TAG, "scan complete " + path);
          }
      });
  ```
- I have also restarted the phone and it still doesn't show.
- In Settings, I have enable Show hidden album but it doesn't show as well.

Current analysis:

- I don't think there's a problem with the image itself because I can see it via File Manager.
- The image path should also correct since some image is shown in the Gallery App.

Note:

I see a forum discussion on this and they suggest to 3rd party app such as Rescan SD Card!. But obviously, it was not the solution I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

try this for saveImage and notify Gallery

https://github.com/wuapnjie/StickerView/blob/master/sticker/src/main/java/com/xiaopo/flying/sticker/StickerUtils.java

Comment: I believe what you mean is using MediaStore, however, it still doesn't work